# Is there a VBA function that could create boolean entries for the days employees have worked?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create boolean entries for the days employees have worked. Here is my sample code:

```
Sub BooleabAtt2()
'Create boolean entries for days worked
'Sign-on Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheets
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sign-ons")
Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("SignOns")
Dim EmployeeName1 As Long
    EmployeeName1 = rng1.Columns("", 2)
Dim DateIn1 As Date
    DateIn1 = rng1.Columns("", 6)
Dim Company1 As Long
    Company1 = rng1.Colums("", 3)
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Employee ID Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheets
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("EmployeeID")
    
'ConsecutiveDays worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheets
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("Consecutive-Days")
Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng3 = ws3.Range("ConsecutiveDays")
Dim EmployeeName

'conditional statement
With rng1
    LastRow = .Colums(2).Rows.Count
    For i = LastRow
        If ws3.rng3.Cells(1, i) = DateIn1 Then
            If ws3.rng3.Cells(i, 2) = EmployeeName1 Then Enter 1
            Otherwise "0"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Below is some sample data

[Excel sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOvI9.png)

The table below is what I am trying to achieve:

[Final worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7vPR.png)

Comment: You can do this with a formula. Is VBA a necessity?

Comment: Any simple solution is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree this could easily be done with formulas. First, to create a list of unique employees, either go to data> remove duplicates, or use a formula like [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list). I think there's also a unique formula if you have the newest version of excel

Then use the formula `=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$11,B$1,$E$2:$E$11,$A2)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot at it using VBA.

Source table (named "timesheet")

[image]

```
Public Function CreateMyPivotTable()

''' Source, destination, and pivot table name variables. '''
''' We're using Sheet1 and Sheet2 for our worksheets, but you
''' could probably add those as a parameter.
Dim source_worksheet_name As String: source_worksheet_name = "Sheet1"
Dim source_tablename As String: source_tablename = "timesheet"
Dim destination_worksheet_name As String: destination_worksheet_name = "Sheet2"
Dim pivot_table_name As String: pivot_table_name = "PivotTimeSheet"


Dim source_worksheet As Worksheet
Dim destination_worksheet As Worksheet

''' Create source and destination worksheet objects.
Set source_worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(source_worksheet_name)
Set destination_worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(destination_worksheet_name)

''' Create source and pivot table objects
Dim src_tbl As ListObject
Dim pivot_tbl As PivotTable


''' Focus on destinaton worksheet.
source_worksheet.Select

''' Set source table variable.
Set src_tbl = source_worksheet.ListObjects(source_tablename)


''' Clear out pivot table (function is below.
Call RemovePivotTable(pivot_table_name)

''' Generate pivotcache using our table source.
With ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=src_tbl.Range.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))
    ''' Create pivot table at A1 in the destination worksheet.
    Call .CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=destination_worksheet.Range("A1"), tablename:=pivot_table_name)
End With

''' Focus on destinaton worksheet.
destination_worksheet.Select

''' Set EmployeeName and Date in as Row and Column fields
''' Use count of Date in per EmployeeName as value.
With destination_worksheet.PivotTables(pivot_table_name)
    ''' Miss me with that Grand Total stuff
    .RowGrand = False
    .ColumnGrand = False
    
    ''' Fill any missing values with Zero.
    .NullString = "0"
    
    ''' General pivot action. Pretty self explanatory.
    With .PivotFields("EmployeeName")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With .PivotFields("Date in")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ''' Data field section
    With .PivotFields("Date in")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount ' Count dates per employee
        .NumberFormat = "0" ' General number format.
    End With
End With

''' Clear objects before leaving.
Set source_worksheet = Nothing
Set destination_worksheet = Nothing
Set src_tbl = Nothing
Set pivot_tbl = Nothing

End Function

Public Function RemovePivotTable(pivot_table_name As String)
''' Delete a pivot table by name.
''' Ex. usage -
'''     RemovePivotTable("PivotTimeSheet")

If Len(pivot_table_name) > 0 Then
    ''' In general, iterate over each worksheet, 
    ''' look for a name match
    ''' then clear out that pivot table.
    Dim pvttbl As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pvttbl In ws.PivotTables
            If pvttbl.Name = pivot_table_name Then
                pvttbl.TableRange2.Clear
            End If
        Next pvttbl
    Next ws
    Set pvttbl = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End If

End Function
```

Output (on Sheet2):

[image]

EDIT: The best way to get a count of 1 in each pivot cell is by removing duplicate values in the table.  That could be done manually, but I recorded a macro that produced the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("timesheet[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 3), Header:=xlYes
```

(Remember skip the `No.` column or else no rows will be removed since all of those values are unique.)

Once that's done, this will be your output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Hi, is there a way we  can show "1" for someone who signed on 2 times that day?

Comment: @CarolineOlyn For sure.  If you can hang on until tomm., I could probably edit he post.

Comment: @CarolineOlyn Okay, I updated the post. Pretty much, just remember to use only unique Names and Dates in the pivot table.  The rest of the code is unchanged.